# SAS compare character records according to 2 different variable groupings

Tags: sas

I am trying to find records which do are not grouped similarly according to 2 different variables (all variables have character format).

My variables are `appln_id` (unique) `earliest_filing_id` (groupings) `docdb_family_id` (groupings). The data set comprises around 25,000 different `appln_id`, but only 15446 different `earliest_filing_id` and 15755 `docdb_family_id`. Now you see that there's a difference of ca. 300 records among these 2 groups (potenially more because groupings might also change).

Now what I would like to do is the see all cases, which are not similarly grouped. Here an example:

```
appln_id      earliest_filing_id  docdb_family_id
10137202      10137202            30449399
10272131      10137202            30449399
10272153      10137202            !!25768424!!
```

You can see that the last case differs and should be on my list that I hope to create.
I was trying to solve it with either a Proc compare, a Call sortc or a by+if...then coding but failed so far to come up with a good solution.
I am not using SAS for that long yet...

Your help is super appreciated!

Grazie

Annina

Comment: Do you mean that when the value of either EARLIEST_FILING_ID or DOCDB_FAMILY_ID change you want to make a new group number?  Did you try using BY group processing in a data step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use BY group processing to assign a new group variable.
Make sure your data is sorted and then run something like this to create a new GROUPID variable.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by EARLIEST_FILING_ID DOCDB_FAMILY_ID ;
  groupid + first.docdb_family_id ;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, that goes into the right direction but I want to even go one step further. Is there a way to now extract the subgroup of records which have the same EARLIEST_FILING_ID but as least 2 different groupid which I just assigned? (If they are the same, then it means for me that the groups between earliest and docdb are the same, but I look for the difference. And I am interested by this definition only in the records which share their EARLIEST_FILING_ID with at least one other record. If it is just one record, obvisouly the groupid will change coherently)

Comment: Use SQL.  `select * from want group by earliest_filing_id having count(distinct groupid) > 1`

Comment: It says "The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data. No rows were selected." I have all 3 columns plus the groupid one in this dataset though...

Comment: I would say put together an example or two and post as new question.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to select unique docdb_family_id. Try this:

```
proc sql;
   select * from yourfile group by docdb_family_id having count(*)=1;
quit;
```

Comment: no, that's not what I meant. I am looking for those single variables (appln_id) which are not grouped in the same group in both variables. Sometimes I have just one appln_id in each group which is fine. But then I have up to 10-15 appln_id which have the same earliest_filling_id but 13 have the same dodb_family_id and the 2 others have one or two  different ones. These last 2 ones are the ones I want to seperate out...

Comment: So you mean those records were grouped in earliest_filling_id, but was individual  by dodb_family_id?